# Unable to obtain AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, mac-catalyst

Yet another Mac Catalyst porting issue. Code that works perfectly in iOS for obtaining an AVCaptureDevice for the purposes of video is failing and returning nil when run on macOS.

The easiest way to demonstrate this issue is with Apple's own [AvCam demo app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app#). It is provided in both Swift and Objective-C. Both fail in the same way. Check the "Mac" checkbox and build and run on a Mac. Grant permission for the camera and then notice the error in the console.

In the Swift version, look at the `configureSession` method of CameraViewController. The lines:

```
var defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

// Choose the back dual camera, if available, otherwise default to a wide angle camera.

if let dualCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
    defaultVideoDevice = dualCameraDevice
} else if let backCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
    // If a rear dual camera is not available, default to the rear wide angle camera.
    defaultVideoDevice = backCameraDevice
} else if let frontCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) {
    // If the rear wide angle camera isn't available, default to the front wide angle camera.
    defaultVideoDevice = frontCameraDevice
}
```

always result in `nil` even though camera permission has been granted.

Or look at the `configureSession` method of the AVCamCameraViewController class in the Objective-C version. The same code for trying to get the AVCaptureDevice fails.

I've also tried to use the `AVCaptureDevice default(for:)` method and I've tried to use `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession devices`. All attempts fail when run on a Mac and all work when run on an iOS device.

What makes this more interesting is that in my own app that has the same issue as the AvCam demo app, I can take photos and capture video just fine using UIImagePickerController. This means that in general, a Mac Catalyst app can use the Mac's camera for both photos and video.

So the question is, what changes are needed to obtain an AVCaptureDevice for video? Can anyone figure out what changes are needed for the AvCam demo app to make it work when run with Mac Catalyst?

Answer (score 7):

This note on the [Cameras and Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture) documentation page states that this is by design:

> **Important**
>
> iPad apps running in macOS cannot use the AVFoundation Capture classes. These apps should instead use UIImagePickerController for photo and video capture.

There is also the [How to get the AVCam demo app to work under Mac Catalyst?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124652) thread on the Apple Developer Forums which includes a statement from Apple support that this behaves as intended.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to update the AVCaptureDevice documentation to make this clearer. I've also filed an enhancement request to get this all supported in Mac Catalyst.